# python minesweeper reveal function

Tags: python, minesweeper

```
def reveal(board, row, col):
  board[row][col] = "C" + board[row][col][1]
  count = 0
  board =[]
  rowcount = 0
  for i in board:
      if count in mines:
          i = 'C*'
      print("| ", i, end=" ")
      if rowcount == 9:
          print("|")
          rowcount = 0
      else:
          rowcount += 1
      count += 1

  board = []
  mines = []
  for i in range(9):
   board.append([])
  for j in range(12):
    board[i].append('C*')

  for i in range(9):
    for j in range(12):
      #Error Below it says Index Not in Range
      print("|", board[i][j], end=" ")
  print("|")
  mines = []
  for i in range(9):

    loc = random.randint(0, 99)
  while loc in mines:
      loc = random.randint(0, 99)
  #board[loc] = 'C*'
  bombs.append(loc)
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm getting an Index Error where I've indicated and I don't know what it means or how to go about changing it. This is the reveal function of my minesweeper game and my board won't draw when running the program

Comment: Can you be more specific and maybe not vote down my question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick guess is this:

```
for i in range(9):
 board.append([])
for j in range(12):
  board[i].append('C*')
```

Intended like that, it runs two independent loops, so `i` will have the last value (`8`) and you only append to the last row.

If you fix your indentation it would look like this:

```
for i in range(9):
    board.append([])
    for j in range(12):
        board[i].append('C*')
```

Then, it will work correctly.

That’s why you should use an indentation size of more than *one space*, so you actually see the difference!

Comment: Thank you so so much! I've added more spaces in my code now for indenting purposes and I can really tell the difference! You're the best!